# Classes with errors do not have a red cross next to them in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I have multiple classes with various errors. However, all classes with such errors in the `Project Explorer` are displayes as if they did not have any errors (i.e. there is no red `x` in the bottom left hand side of the `J` icon to the left to the name of the class).

How do I fix this? I have tried:

- Cleaning project.
- Refreshing project.
- Restarting `Eclipse`.

None of the above have worked.

Comment: restart the eclipse ..

Comment: @NiksTyagi I did that already..

Comment: What are the errors in question? Sometimes the editor displays errors that aren't actually errors, especially if postprocessing like AspectJ is involved.

Comment: i guess you need to use new eclipse ..

Comment: @chrylis `The import com.X.Y.Z cannot be resolved`, `Syntax error`, ... anything really. In other `Java` projects it'll be fine.

Comment: Ok now this new project can't even run main class files. Lol.

Comment: Have you looked at the *Errors* view? If you double-click on an error there, the source file will open.

Answer (score 0):

did you unchecked build automatically in

**Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build automatically**

also in **project > Build automatically**

or

set your `java build path` and `java Compiler` in project properties to the right settings

Comment: `MainProject/src` is the build path. I'm not sure what setting the `java Compiler` entails?

Comment: @user2763361: did you set the java version compatible with jre in `java compiler`?